# How to take a value from a link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass one value through ajax by taking the values from jQuery. But I am using link so I have problems taking the value. I tried the following,

```
<a id="addpa" class="ActionPopup" href="http://localhost:49951/admin/assignhome/Add?sPId=7">Add</a>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
var spId = $("#addpa").prop("href"); // Here i am getting a whole Url
var thequerystring = getParameterByName("sPId");
```

The result is showing undefined. How to take the value of sPId? Give me ideas..

Comment: What is `getParameterByName` ?

Comment: I google it. One solution they declare getParameterByName..So I tried to get the value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Comment: PS: Please read the comments to each answer in the duplicate. There are some good points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to take the value of sPId?

Try using `String.prototype.split()` , `Array.prototype.pop()`

```
var spId = $("#addpa").prop("href").split(/=/).pop();
```

Comment: Is it prototype instead of protiotype